# Downgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, 22.04, downgrade

I was wondering if there is a way to downgrade the OS of a server from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa). I am setting up a local Galaxy (usegalaxy.org) server and ran into multiple compatibility issues due to having Ubuntu 22.04 as the OS. I have little computational knowledge (biology student), so I was wondering if I needed to wipe the entire server (if yes, how would i do this?) or if I can install the Ubuntu 20.04 on the server and if this would get rid of 22.04 installation in the process.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

(I have seen similar topics on the AskUbuntu forum, but since my knowledge about servers is limited, I couldn't find a solution I fully understood or taught was applicable to my problem)

Comment: Short summary: There is no supported downgrade path - but you can possibly do it, using any of the "hacky methods" given in the duplicate answer. But this is totally unsupported. Your best option is probably to reinstall 20.04.

Comment: Especially if you just started this process, it will be a lot easier to start over and reinstall.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thank you so much! Since my knowledge on this topic is very limited, do you perhaps know if installing Ubuntu 20.04 with a bootable USB created with Rufus would install Ubuntu 20.04 and alongside remove the Ubuntu 22.04 installation as well as everything previously installed on the server? Thanks in advance!